# How to export 3d object as a .tri file? blender 2.77

Tags: modeling, texturing, export

I am trying to use raydium game engine but i cannot find a way to export my 3d images as .tri files can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an english version of [this page](http://wiki.raydium.org/wiki/BlenderVersTri) - [translate.google](https://translate.google.com) provides the following -

> Export of creations made with Blender to Raydium is possible using the Python script triEXP * comes with sources Raydium.
>
> Use:
>
> Load this script into Blender (BlenderChargerScript), "triangulate" the object in Blender (CTRL + T, in edit mode, after you select all the point with the key), and run the script (ALT + P in the window contains the Python script). This operation performed, a file dialog appears where you can choose the export and the name of the file directory.
>
> You will have a little more information in the console from which you started Blender, especially in case of errors.
>
> !! Warning !! verify that you are in object mode before running the script.
>
> Note: This script does not export the path to the textures, and therefore considers that the textures are always in the same directory as the exported .tri.
>
> See also, for other import / export solutions ImportExportTri

If you look in the source download you will find a blender folder that has several scripts, the startup/tri_import_export_264.py can be loaded in blender's text editor and run to add the .tri import/export options. A simple test shows it to work, if it fails with your models than ask for help improving it with info and examples of what fails.